# Toggle switch is not working propertly in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using a toggle switch in my html. I can get the data from the database and render it correctly in my toggle switch. On loading, when my value is true, my toggle reflects true, so when I change it to false, my "ngModel" changes to false too and can update my database. But if on load and my toggle is false, when I change the toggle state to true, it does not get reflected in my ngModel. Meaning, the toggle changes from false to true but the "ngModel" does not reflect the change at all. Please see my code below.

**at .html**

```
<div class="togglebutton">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
        [checked]="selectedUser.IsActivated" (change)="$event.target.cheked ? (selectedUser.IsActivated = true) : (selectedUser.IsActivated = false)"> User Activated {{selectedUser.IsActivated}}
    </label>
</div>
```

**at .ts**

```
onEdit() {
    debugger;
    const user: User = {
      Id:         this.selectedUser.Id,         
      UserName:   this.selectedUser.UserName,    
      Password:   "",
      Email:      this.selectedUser.Email,       
      FirstName:  this.selectedUser.FirstName,   
      MiddleName: this.selectedUser.MiddleName, 
      LastName:   this.selectedUser.LastName,    
      IsActivated: this.selectedUser.IsActivated
    }
    this.us.registerUser(user)
      .subscribe((data:any)=>{
        if (data.Succeeded) {
          this.gs.showSwal('success-message');
          this.getUsers();
          this.selectedUser = null;
        }
      });
  }
```

The div is in a modal. Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: `$event.target.cheked` > typo. I think it should be `checked`

Comment: You are talking about `ngModel` but you are not using it. Why?

Comment: @PriyeshKumar: Thank you. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `selectedUser.IsActivated` property to the checkbox with `[(ngModel)]`. If the HTML snippet is inside a `form` container, make sure that the input field has a unique name. In the code below, the `div` is displayed only when `selectedUser` is not `null` or `undefined`.

```
<div class="togglebutton" *ngIf="!!selectedUser">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="activated" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.IsActivated">
    User Activated {{selectedUser.IsActivated}}
  </label>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzxw7z) for a demo.

Comment: That was the first thing that I did. Somehow it doesn't work. So I came up with this code.

Comment: You may see an error in the console because `selectedUser` is not always defined. I will update my answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to account for cases where `selectedUser` is `null`.

Comment: This how I used your suggestion Sir. <div class="togglebutton" *ngIf="!!selectedUser">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" 
                                                [(ngModel)]="selectedUser.IsActivated"> Is User Activated? => {{selectedUser.IsActivated}}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>

Comment: Do you see any error in the console when running that code? If the input field is in a `form`, it should have a unique `name`, as shown in the updated answer.